# enforce some peers to use IPsec and allow others to bypass it when reaching the same server

Tags: authentication, network, ipsec

Lets assume I have a server that owns UDP socket. And then, for some clients, this server would expect to receive this UDP traffic encapsulated over IPsec. While for some others clients (the default), it lets them to contact the same server in Plain text without using any IPsec.

To me this seems something like "opportunistic authentication", because the clients that don't require authentication can still reach server's UDP socket over plain and could even try to spoof traffic under some circumstances so that it would look as if it came from a host that was expected to communicate over IPsec.

What security experts say about such security designs? Are there any certifications (FIPS etc) that prohibit such designs because it effectively means that server is letting attacker to bypass IPsec authentication and Application Layer would have to make decision whether traffic was spoofed or not.

Answer (score 1):

> ... letting attacker to bypass IPsec authentication and Application Layer would have to make decision whether traffic was spoofed or not.

UDP is a transport layer protocol, while IPSec is a network layer protocol. Contrary to higher layer security protocols like TLS the server application will not be able to tell if the data were sent through IPSec or plain, it only sees the application data. In order to distinguish this you need to have different endpoints (IP address and/or port) for IPSec and plain traffic.

> ...for some clients, this server would expect to receive this UDP traffic encapsulated over IPsec. While for some others... without using any IPsec.

With a normal network setup there should only be a single route to the server host, which is either through the VPN (IPSec) or not. Thus a client would need to be taken outside of the VPN to connect in plain to the server or the server need to have a second address which is not in the route of the VPN.

This means the default does probably what it should do. But one has to question the decision to let all client connect by default without encryption. Instead I would recommend to maybe allow local clients (same network) without encryption, to allow for some other clients connection through VPN and to forbid all other clients to connect at all.

But I think your question lacks enough detail to decide if the setup is safe or not. I think you can build both a safe setup and an insecure setup which both match your current description of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic in clear text and traffic over IPSEC are two different concepts.
 As per my understanding, either the application on the server should be capable of receiving traffic on single port and differentiate between clear text and encrypted text ;or there should be a different port to receive IPSEC traffic and then process it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to points mentioned above, an important factor to consider here is about where the server is placed. If you have router or firewall ahead of the server, we can have the IPSEC (VPN) terminated on the device which would then decrypt the traffic and forward the UDP/TCP traffic to the server.

Ideally it depends on what services are hosted and what is the topology of the network.

Hope it clarifies the doubt